# How to check every element in array before breaking

Tags: java

```
if((Integer.parseInt(indexesString[i]) > 0 && Integer.parseInt(indexesString[i]) <= 12)) {
    break outerloop;
}
```

How can I check if all element in `IndexesString` is between 1 and 12 before breaking? Now it only checks if the first element is between 1 and 12 and breaks then without checking if the rest is valid.

```
"1 13" should not break
"1 12" should break
```

EDIT: The input is a string. For example "1" or "1 2 12", which is split in separate strings for each number.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you can do is set a boolean true, then loop over all elements and do the check. If one of them is not in between 1 and 12, set the boolean to false. After the loop, break if the boolean is true.

Comment: @MWB Yes, this was it, thank you! Do you also know how to check if it is not any special character except an asterisk?

Comment: Sidenote: If the array was sorted to begin with, you could check the first and last elements only, that way you'd avoid the costly O(n) complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Mark's answer looks too complicated to you try this. In order to *check if all elements in `IndexesString`* are within a certain range we'll have to iterate through the `IndexesString`. So put your `if` statement inside another `for` loop.

```
boolean allWithinRenge = true;

for (String s : indexesString) { //iterate through indexesString
    if (!(Integer.parseInt(s) > 0 && Integer.parseInt(s) <= 12)) { //check the range of each element
        allWithinRenge = false;
        break; //break this loop, because an element is not within the range
    }
}

if (allWithinRenge) {
    // all numbers are within 1 and 12
} else {
    break yourLoop;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did this because MWB's comment on my question. I'll mark yours as answer because it's what worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use functions from the stream api. Code is below:

For further reading about [allMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-)

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Between {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> indexesString = new ArrayList<String>() {{
      add("1");
      add("9");
      add("4");
    }};

    if (indexesString.stream().allMatch(s -> 0 < Integer.parseInt(s) && Integer.parseInt(s) <= 12)) {
      System.out.println("break!!!");
    } else {
      System.out.println("something happened");
    }
  }
}
```